# tomcat still writes application log in catalina.out though i undeployed the application

Tags: java, tomcat, catalina.out

I deployed an application in Apache tomcat in a centOS server and after a while my application faced a connection reset error.
As my application writes everything in catalina.out so I found that it's writing error log infinitely in catalina.out.

Now, Though I stop and undeployed the application from tomcat, still catalina.out is written with that infinite connection.reset log. i found that only shutdown tomcat stops this writing.

How I can fix this uncontrolled writing? I want to stop writing in catalina.out when I stop/undeployed this application.

Comment: how did you stop/undeployed the application, (it is war file correct)

Comment: From tomcat manager-gui